# What do I put in Authorization header for calls to API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am able to call my rest api in api gateway by passing the users IdToken in the Authorization header when using Cognito User Pools.

However now I'm trying to call api gateway using Cognito federated identities, therefore an iam user. What do I send in the Authorization header in this case?

I'm calling lambda using proxy+

Answer (score 0):

If you have done the part with Cognito with user pool and federated identifies, you can use `AWS_IAM` as authorizer.

```
  get:
    handler: get.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

Comment: Cool, this is what I'm doing with serverless. But what do I send in the HTTP Authorization header instead of the IDToken?

Comment: the ID token is sent as bearer authorization (BASE64) in header.

Comment: If the authorization is done with `AWS_IAM`, shouldn't the `Authorization` header be the result of a sig4 signing process?